# Clearing Android activity stack without animation (silently)

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities, A and B.

1) From activity A you can go to B and return to A via back button (resume).

2) From activity A you can go to B, make a selection, which will return to activity A via reloading it. Here I need to clear out the previous copy of activity A from the back stack.

In the second case I am using the following intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

This works, but my new activity is drawn first, then I can see the old copy getting removed - so there's some animation of the same activity going away. Is there any way to either reverse that behaviour so that the old activity is removed first, or alternatively get rid of that animation? Thanks!

EDIT:

In terms of a workaround, for now I'm setting activity A as a `singleTask` in manifest, overriding `onNewIntent` and resetting all my objects that I need to reload in `onResume`. That seems to be working but I'd prefer a clean slate, i.e. reload the activity

Comment: Why do you reload activity A from activity B instead of just returning the selection to A via [Activity.setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)?

Comment: Well the selection is a fundamental change. Essentially activity B allows the user to join a project, and activity A is a representation of that project. So if I simply return the selection, there's a lot of things I need to reload, redraw and change - it's cleaner to reload the whole thing

Comment: Why did you call: `startActivity(intent);` and then `finish();`? Remove `finish()`

Comment: @dieter_h I don't want activity B to stay in the stack - it's done the job, started activity A, don't need it anymore, hence `finish`

Comment: Try to use: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` instead of  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: yep, tried that - did nothing at all